# Independent RVs theorem: rigorous?

Tags: probability, self-study, independence

I am reproducing here theorem (#3.30) from "All of Statistics" by Larry Wasserman:

> Let X and Y have joint pdf $f_{X,Y}$ . Then $X\perp Y$ if and only if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$ for all values x and y.

$X\perp Y$ means X and Y independent random variables.

On the left margin it is accompanied by a comment:

> The statement is not rigorous because the density is defined only up to sets of measure 0.

I am having hard time making any sense out of the comment. I am looking for the the following:

- Any example where the above theorem does not hold; assuming that theorem is not rigorous implies there are some loose strings.
- Explanation of the phrase "sets of measure 0" and how it relates to the current theorem. (I am familiar with probability measure)
- The rigorous version of the theorem.

Comment: A correct statement would be that there exist a version of $f_{X,Y}$ and versions of $f_X$ and $f_Y$ such that the equality holds. Or equivalently that the equality holds almost everywhere.

Comment: Maybe this example will help you: the function $f$ defined by $$f(x)=\mathbf 1_{[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q}(x),$$ is a perfectly legitimate PDF for the standard uniform distribution $U$ on $[0,1]$ since, for every Borel subset of $\mathbb R$, $$\int_Bf(x)\mathrm dx=\int_{B\cap[0,1]}\mathrm dx=U(B).$$